# Jboss infinispan does not exist on this cache manager

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jboss6.x, infinispan

I have 2 diffrent jboss seperated from each other but on same net. (JbossAS 6.1)

I have and applicaton that runs well on one server. that uses infispan as secondlevel cache with hibernate.

but on the other sever i get the following message, how do i configure it so the both jbosses can cache the application from server one.

```
 [org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl] (Incoming-20,null) Cache named persistence.unit:unitName=se.syll.plattform-ear.ear/se.syll.jobbcomponent-ejb.jar#se.syll.jobbcomponent.org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache does not exist on this cache manager!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing a problem which affected JBoss 6 around asymmetric caches: you have to make sure all caches are defined in the same way on each node, and started approximately at the same time.

The better solution is to move on to JBoss AS 7.1.